# Value doesn't change after passing by reference

Tags: c++, variables, reference

```
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;


void v6(char rq,int &cost)
{
    if(rq=='2')
        cost+=1;

    if(rq=='1')
        cost+=2;

    if(rq=='3')
        cost+=3;
}

int main()
{
    int cost=0;
    v6(2,cost);
    cout<<cost;
}
```

Output: 
`0`

However, the value - passed by reference- of `c` doesn't change; please explain how.

used pointers too , but to no avail

Comment: You are passing `2` as `int` not `char` and hence the conditions are faiing in the function. Call v6 as `v6('2',control,cost);`

Comment: @Wander3r You could have added this as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I slight change in your function call should give you the behavior you want

```
v6('2',cost);
```

Your `if` statements checkt for a `char` and not for a number. Either you apply the changes stated above or you change the `if` statements

```
void v6(char rq,int &cost)
{
    if(rq==2)
        cost+=1;

    if(rq==1)
        cost+=2;

    if(rq==3)
        cost+=3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `Numeric 2` instead of `char 2` in the function call.

`v6(2,cost);` has to be replaced with `v6('2',cost);`

Passing `2` pass the ASCII equivalent of 2 (http://www.asciitable.com/).

ASCII equivalent of `'2'` is 50 in numeric. So, `v6(50,cost);` or `v6('2',cost);` will give you the same result.